# 401 is returned as result of multipart/form-data request in React application

Tags: ajax, multipartform-data, fetch-api

I am trying to send image to server via multipart/form-data request:

```
        const formData  = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', myfile);//myfile is retrieved from input with type="file"     
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('PUT', url, false);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer myvalue").value);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=myvalue");
        xhr.send(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState != 4) return;

            if (this.status != 200) {
                return;
            }
        }
```

But 401 is returned. At the same time I do this request via Insomnia, and everything is fine - 200 is returned.

Also I tried Fetch API to do this request, but 401 is returned.

Why this request is valid from Insomnia, but not from browser?

And one more question: I noticed that boundary in `Content-type` differs from boundary in Request payload. I'm not sure if it is right. Can someone please explain why they are different?

[image]